# VirtualBox on SSD - Macbook Air

Tags: linux, macos, virtualbox, ssd

I have a MacBook Air with a 256GB SSD. I want to use VirtualBox to run a Linux distribution alongside with OS X. If I create, say a 20GB virtual hard disk in which to install the Linux distribution, how will this affect my SSD? Will every write operation within the Linux virtual machine, cause the whole 20GB virtual hard disk to be rewritten to my SSD?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a fixed-sized virtual disk, Virtual Box will write to that file and not rewrite it from the beginning.

Also, based on the comments and some research, I have concluded this: The fixed size virtual disk is faster than a dynamic one. So the fixed size virtual disk is not rewritten. With the fixed virtual disk, you only write the new information after the old information. If you have to edit some information in the Guest OS (In your case Linux), the virtual machine will edit only that information and not editing the whole file.

Comment: But if I the virtual hard disk is one big file (fixed size), won't any modification of that file mean that the whole thing file will be rewritten to the SSD? Or do only the parts of the file that are modified be rewritten to new parts of the SSD? (SSD noob, sorry)

Comment: dynamic disks (non-fixed as they were referred in the answer) still have a max fixed size. They can't grow any larger than that. In other words, a fixed disk and a dynamic disk with a virtual size of 20GB will never take up more than 20GB of physical disk space. Dynamic disks also allocate and write blocks as needed - unless you are flushing the entire disk contents it will only write the parts that are being modified.

Comment: @NOP Generally, when a (any!) file is modified, only the changed allocation blocks are written to disk. Except on special filesystems, but that’s not what a SOHO user comes into contact with. Just imagine how long it’d take if the whole were to be written again and again.